# HTML5 reading Iframe body

Tags: html

So I need to get the body code of an Iframe, in javascript or Jquery or whatever to communicate with my server. I set up my iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:9090" name="frame" id="frame"></iframe>
```

and it displays what my http server sent to it just fine, but when I attempt to get the body of my website/HTTP server using this code:

```
var content=$("#frame").contents().find("body").html(); alert(content);
```

But it just returns nothing. PS I am using chrome

Answer (score 0):

If your `iframe` is pointing at a page that is not from the same domain as the page that contains, then the Same Origin Policy will prohibit your page from reading the DOM of the `iframe`.

If you really have a pressing need to know the contents of the `iframe`, then use a library like `CURL` to load the same page on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome or any other browser isn't the problem here. Same-origin policy is. This policy would prevent you to read the content of a site that is hosted at some other domain. Even proxy matters in this case.

You cannot just read the contents of Iframe by just loading it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy Read this to learn more about it.